# Percentages not calculating correctly

Tags: c#

I have a math problem I need to solve for my upcoming C# basics exam. The code below is what I accomplished so far. Let me explain the code:

`int capacity`  is the capacity of a football stadium. [1..10000]

`int fans` is the number of fans attending [1..10000]

`var sector` in the `for` loop is the allocation of each fan among the 4 sectors - A, B, V, G

I need to calculate the percentage of fans in each of the sectors as well as the percentage of all fans relative to the capacity of the stadium.

What is the reason for the results to return 0.00?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FootballTournament
{
    class FootballTournament
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int capacity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int fans = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int sector_A = 0;
            int sector_B = 0;
            int sector_V = 0;
            int sector_G = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < fans; i++)
            {
                var sector = Console.ReadLine();
                if(sector == "A")
                {
                    sector_A++;
                }
                else if (sector == "B")
                {
                    sector_B++;
                }
                else if (sector == "V")
                {
                    sector_V++;
                }
                else if (sector == "G")
                {
                    sector_G++;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0:f2}%", (sector_A / fans * 100));
            Console.WriteLine("{0:f2}%", (sector_B / fans * 100));
            Console.WriteLine("{0:f2}%", (sector_V / fans * 100));
            Console.WriteLine("{0:f2}%", (sector_G / fans * 100));
            Console.WriteLine("{0:f2}%", (fans / capacity * 100));
        }
    }
}
```

Input/output example:

```
Input: 
76
10
A
V
V
V
G
B
A
V
B
B
```

---

```
Output:
20.00%
30.00%
40.00%
10.00%
13.16%
```

Comment: Integer division wouldn't have been a problem by itself if you didn't need the two decimals, for example `sector_A * 100 / fans`. Doesn't really help in your specific case though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing integer math. The outcome will also be an integer.

Change your types to `double`, or cast them in your calculation.

Example

```
53/631 == 0 //integer
53/631d == 0,0839936608557845 //floating point
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an integer division, which results in 0.

In your example you are using `int/int`, which does everything in integer arithmetic even if you're assigning to a decimal/double/float variable.

Force one of the operands to be of the type you want to use for the arithmetic.

```
decimal capacity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
decimal fans = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

decimal sector_A = 0;
decimal  sector_B = 0;
decimal sector_V = 0;
decimal sector_G = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It worked with `double`, too.

Comment: @user3628807 if you find this answer useful please accept it and vote it up so other users could recognize it as useful answer also. Thanks and you are welcome.